# In Oracle, is there a datatype for what follows the IN operator?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a question about Oracle PL/SQL.

In a procedure the same embedded SELECT statement is repeatedly used with WHERE clauses in queries:

```
...
where start_year in (
   SELECT MB_START FROM MEMBERS
)
...
```

The actual SELECT statement embedded in the WHERE clause in the procedure is 
more elaborate, and is replaced with 'SELECT MB_START FROM MEMBERS' to make
my question here easier to follow.  And that is exactly why I am asking the 
question:

Repeating the same sub-query in many WHERE clauses is cumbersome, makes 
the clogged code difficult to read, and is a potential waste of the server 
resource.  Is there a way to have what the embedded sub-query returns saved in a variable, such as:

```
DECLARE
   start_years <type_for_IN_operator>;
BEGIN
   ...
   select mb_start into start_years from members;
   ...
   WHERE start_year in (start_years)
   ...
END;
/
```

I searched hard and have not been able to find out if Oracle supports saving values in a variable to be used by the IN operator.  If it is supported, what is the datatype for type_for_IN_operator?

### Response to the answers and further question:

Thank you all for your answers to the question.

I asked the question because I observed that the IN operator accepts a set of values in different forms, such as

- literals: IN (2015, 2016, 2017)
- a column selected from a table:  IN (select mb_start from members)
- a collection via a SELECT statment:  in (select column_value from table(collection))

therefore I thought they may have something in common, such as of a datatype that I do not know.  If there is such a datatype, query code could be much simpler and easier.

I am attracted by APC's idea, especially it is pure sql and the virtual table is reusable.  I tried it, but went to a problem.

The script originally was:

```
select t.col1, t.col2, ... from
(
  select ...
  from ...
  where start_year in (<that subquery>)
  union
  select ...
  from ...
  where start_year in (<that subquery>)
  union
  ...
) t
join ...
...
```

Now using the virtual table and replace the first original subquery:

```
with sqf as (
    SELECT MB_START FROM MEMBERS
)
select t.col1, t.col2, ... from
(
  select ...
  from ...
  where start_year in (select * from sqf)
  union
  select ...
  from ...
  where start_year in (<that subquery>)
  union
  ...
) t
join ...
...
```

And it happened that the query completed even a bit faster than the original code.  However, when the second <that subquery> is also replaced with the sqf virtual table, the query ran forever, though it did not spit any error either.  I had to kill it.  I tried a couple more times and it behaved the same way.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to have what the embedded sub-query returns saved in a variable

Sort of. It's the WITH clause, otherwise known as subquery factoring. It's been part of the Oracle SQL capability since 9i.

Using your posted example:

```
with sqf as (
    SELECT MB_START FROM MEMBERS
)
select * from your_table
where col1 in ( select * from sqf )
and col2 in  ( select * from sqf )
and col3 not in ( select * from sqf )
/
```

The WITH clause is executed once and reused in subsequent references. We can use it in the FROM clause, including the FROM clause of other subquery factors.

The obvious beauty of this is that it's pure SQL, so no need for PL/SQL, variables or type declarations. There is one gotcha, which is that Oracle may choose to materialise large result sets, which means writing to and reading from disk.

Answer (score 3):

Any query in oracle returns a cursor based on which columns are selected. It doesn't matter whether you call it inside IN condition.

However if you want to save results of your subquery to be reused in multiple queries, you can create a TYPE and bulk collect your values in it.

```
CREATE TYPE MEMBER_TAB_TYPE AS TABLE OF DATE;

DECLARE 
  MB_START_TABLE MEMBER_TAB_TYPE;
BEGIN 
  SELECT MB_START BULK COLLECT INTO MB_START_TABLE FROM MEMBERS;
  ....
  WHERE START_YEAR IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(MB_START_TABLE));
  ....
END;
```

You can use MB_START_TABLE as many times as you want in your program without actually querying into MEMBERS table, as **"SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(MB_START_TABLE)"** will always get the locally stored values.

Comment: If the result set of the first query is small, this is a nice solution. For large result sets however, it takes away many query optimization opportunities because the code forces Oracle to materialize the intermediate result. So saving code might come at a price.

Comment: Agreed. However, the assumption is that since he is using the data set within IN condition, data set won't be very large and memory footprint will be miniscule.

Comment: This is all true but misses the point that Oracle has provided a way to solve this problem in pure SQL since Oracle 9i: the WITH clause.

Answer (score 0):

`IN` is logically a series of `=` expressions with `OR` between them, so in effect you are asking for the datatype for equality tests.

In your example, it looks like  `mb_start` is a `date`, so you will need to define a standalone `table of date` collection type if you don’t already have one, which you can then use in a `table()` or `member of` expression.

Comment: How about a WITH clause?

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions work, but at a cost.

It takes 23 seconds for the original code to complete the query.  40 second for factored subquery.  52 second for using collection (select column value from table(collection)).  Plus, the original code has to be modified a bit for the two alternatives to work.

The original query works OK, and this is its framework:

```
select col1, col2 from
(
   SELECT x.col_a, x.col_b, ... from ...
   where
   (
      ( conditions A AND condition B)
      OR
      ( condition C AND condition D AND condition E)
   )
   AND
   condition F
   UNION
   select B
   UNION
   select C
) x
JOIN ...
JOIN ...
...
```

But the factored subquery and the collection alternatives both get choked, run forever without producing results, unless the SELECT before the first UNION operator is split into two, so there is one more UNION:

```
select col1, col2 from
(
   SELECT x.col_a, x.col_b, ... from ...
   where
      conditions A AND condition B AND condition F
   UNION
   SELECT col_a, col_b, ... from ...
   where
      condition C AND condition D AND condition E AND condition F
   UNION
   select B
   UNION
   select C
) x
JOIN ...
JOIN ...
...
```

So, at least with my case, between the old code and new alternatives, it is a trade-off between performance and neater code.

(I tried clicking the check mark to mark both alternatives as solutions, but stackoverflow does not allow and toggles between the two.  Sorry for that, and thank you all for your help.)